# Keep going through foreach if I returned true once

Tags: php, drupal

I got this array inside another array which I need to search/match then return true. Problem is that the foreach just stop after the 1st match.

```php
foreach($term_data as $key => $terms){
    if (false !== $searchkey = array_search(113, array_column($terms[services], 'target_id'))){
        $handler->argument = $term_data[$key]['id'];
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        return FALSE; 
    }
}
```

My array is something like :

```
$term_data = Array (
    [0] Array (
        [id] => 35
        [name] => 'Location1'
        [services] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [target_id] => 112
                )
            [1] => Array (
                [target_id] => 113
            )
    )
    [1] Array (
        [id] => 36
        [name] => 'Location2'
        [services] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [target_id] => 109
                )
            [1] => Array (
                [target_id] => 113
            )
    )
)
```

This is used in a Drupal Views. I need to return true each time that it's matched after setting $handler->argument. Right now it works but stop after the 1st match. How would I go over each $term_data, search in the services array, then return the term_data[id].

This work in another View but it's not an array inside another one :

```php
if (false !== $key = array_search($search_name, array_column($term_data, 'name'))){
    $handler->argument = $term_data[$key]['id'];
    return TRUE;
}else{
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Move `return TRUE;` to after the foreach???

Comment: What does return true do for the function that calls this code?

Comment: Calling `return` means that the execution of current function is terminated and execution jump backs to where the function was called from. There is no way to continue foreach once you've called return from it.

Comment: Yeah I get that return just kill the loop. I would need to check the array inside the array without using the foreach which I'm not sure how to do. Like my other example with array_seach just works... I would need something like that but considering the parent array.

Comment: Return either returns to the line after the function call OR if called from the global scope, terminates the script. From what you show us, its not clear if this code is in a function or the global scope

Comment: That would be a function. It's in a Drupal Views argument filter which ask to return true if it pass the validation...

Comment: Would there be a way to use array_search like in my 2nd (working) example ? The search in an array inside another one is messing me up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to check `$term_data` for a match in any of the array items. If so, don't `return false` in the foreach loop - return false *after* the loop, if no matches were found.

```
foreach($term_data as $key => $terms){
    if (false !== $searchkey = array_search(113, array_column($terms[services], 'target_id'))){
        $handler->argument = $term_data[$key]['id'];
        return TRUE;
    }
}

return FALSE;
```

Comment: I dont think you got that the OP wants to check all the occurances for `113` not just the first. Or maybe I am wrong :)

Comment: You got it right. That stops after the first match cause of the return.

Comment: @dmegatool Who got it right? If you want to check all occurrences, don't return in the loop at all. Do something like `$matches[] = $term_data[$key]['id'];` to store an array of matches, then return that, or false if its count is `0` after the loop.

Comment: I tried to return an array but it doesn't work. Like the Drupal function expect a single id of a node. So I need to return handler->argument as an id, each time it's matched...

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to return BOTH/ALL values of `$term_data[$key]['id'];` that match if so you will have to build an array

```
// initialise before array
$handler->argument = [];

foreach($term_data as $key => $terms){
    if (false !== $searchkey = array_search(113, array_column($terms[services], 'target_id'))){
        $handler->argument[] = $term_data[$key]['id'];
    }
}

return count($handler->argument) > 0;    // true if 1 or more occurances else false
```